# How does adding GROUP BY or DISTINCT give the same result set?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, distinct

```
SELECT unit.id,
       unit.unit_name,
       unit.description,
       unit.category_id,
       city.name,
       mealbase.name AS mealbase_name,
       unit.province_id,
       unit.rooms,
       unit.max_people,
       unit.thumblocation,
       prices.normal_price,
       prices.holiday_price
FROM   jos_units AS unit,
       jos_prices AS prices,
       jos_cities AS city,
       jos_meal_basis AS mealbase
WHERE  prices.unit_id = unit.id
       AND city.id = unit.city_id
       AND unit.published = 1
       AND unit.mealbasis_id = mealbase.id
```

When I run this query It gives me redundant result set as below.

[image]

But If I add

`SELECT DISTINCT unit.id` Instead of `SELECT unit.id` at the beginning ***Or*** 
    `GROUP BY unit.unit.id` at the end. It gives me correct result set as below.

[image]

My issue is What's wrong with my query(join above gives redundant result even I have corrected joined them)? Why does the adding `SELECT DISTINCT unit.id` or `GROUP BY unit.unit.id` is same for the query(which fixes the issue) here? (DISTINCT AND GROUP BY are different functionalities)

Given that I know adding `SELECT DISTINCT unit.id will remove the redundant results but how does the adding one of the two snippet gives same result set? Obviously SELECT DISTINCT unit.id should remove redundant rows by how does the GROUP BY do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you are grouping the results without using an aggregation function (using a `COUNT`, or a `MAX`, for examples), thus you get the aggregate row in the same way you would obtain it by selecting `DISTINCT` objects. If you don't need to aggregate them, `DISTINCT` is the right thing to do.

Comment: join above gives redundant result even I have corrected joined them why is it?

Comment: You are joining the tables `units` with `prices` and `cities` with `units`. Where does the `mealbase` tables get joined? If it has multiple values for the same combination of `(city, price, unit)` then you will get duplicates, but that's normal... can you add some data examples?

Comment: unit.mealbasis_id = mealbase.id is used to join the table. all tables are joined corrected.

Comment: Just to be sure of having understood correctly: you have duplicate rows, so the exact same row repeated multiple times? That might happen because you are not exactly joining the tables, you are doing a cross product between those data: have you tried using the `JOIN` construct in your query?

Comment: Thanks a lot. let me try that too.

Answer (score 3):

> join above gives redundant result even I have corrected joined them
>   why is it?

Thats because of how your tables:

- `jos_units`.
- `jos_prices`.
- `jos_cities`.
- `jos_meal_basis`.

are related to each others.

It seems like you have one to many or many to many relations between those tables. For instance, for each record in the `jos_meal_basis`, each meal has a unit, so many meals might be measured by the same unit, then when joining the two tables you will get redundant units because of this. The same with other tables.

Answer (score 1):

Your combination in the first query, ie

```
(unit.id,
       unit.unit_name,
       unit.description,
       unit.category_id,
       city.name,
       mealbase.name AS mealbase_name,
       unit.province_id,
       unit.rooms,
       unit.max_people,
       unit.thumblocation,
       prices.normal_price,
       prices.holiday_price) has duplicates and so you are getting more than 1 rows for the same combination.
```

When you use `distinct clause or group by` it removes duplicates in your above combination. Hope this helps you.

Comment: yes I know that and I have mentioned it in the question. What I want to know is how does it happen?

Comment: join above gives redundant result even I have corrected joined them why is it?

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` is primarily used if you want to use aggregate or group functions. For example if you wanted to find the number of rows that match you could do

```
SELECT
  id
, COUNT(id) num_rows
FROM
...
GROUP BY id
```

because the `COUNT` is an aggregate function you need to group by the other columns. If you aren't doing any aggregate functions, `GROUP BY` is essentially just aggregating the rows up (if that's the way you've written it) causing only one row - the same as `DISTINCT`.

Comment: join above gives redundant result even I have corrected joined them why is it?

Comment: you'll probably have a one-to-many relationship between 2 of the tables. Try building your query bit by bit and checking the rows returned. At some point you'll have changed the cardinality and introduced the additional rows.